# HasMany() not working in Laravel for fetch relationship wise records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

Currently, I'm working on laravel 6 with MySQL database.

So I want to fetch records with has Many relations wise.

[Fetch Training Intensity Records vie multiple ids -- see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drsuD.png)

**TrainingGoalModel.php**

```
/**
 * training_intensity_details => get multiple intensity with current goal
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function training_intensity_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TrainingIntensity::class, 'id', 'training_intensity_ids');
}
```

**GoalController**

```
$query = $query->with('training_intensity_details')->get();
```

*,both applied,*

```
$query = $query->with(['training_intensity_details'])->get();
```

But, Relation not applying.
Please, Help me.

Comment: Relationship cannot work on comma separated ids. if you have hasMany relation with TrainingIntensity's table, then you should add goal id in training_intensities table instead of storing in goals table.

Comment: Can we manage customised relationship for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try..**

```
   public function training_intensity_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TrainingIntensity::class, 'training_intensity_ids', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it